# Some doubts using cloudwatch metrics for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I created a DynamoDB table.

And now Im trying to create a Cloudwatch alarm to send a SNS notification when tables request exceed 80% for 1 hour (as it appear when we create a DynamoDB table using AWS management console).

My doubts are:

1. I need to create two cloud watch alarms, as the code below? Or there is a way to create only 1 alarm with both metrics?
2. And also, for this example that Im trying to do Sum is the correct metric right?
3. When we create a table with AWS management console and it appears to create a cloud watch alarm when tables request exceed 80%, also appears that the SNS notification will bet sent when:

Read Capacity Units consumed > 1
or
Write Capacity Units consumed > 1

I'm bit confused with this part, the SNS notification will be sent when read capacity units consumed and write capacity units consumed > 1 or when table request exceeds 80% for 1 hour? Or it is the same thing? If it is the same thing if 1 read and 1 write unity corresponds to  1 read and 1 write per second, when the read and write capacity units consumed is > 1, if we configured that we want just 1 unit? When the Cloudwatch alarm starts?

```
def createCW(topicArn, tableName):
    cloudwatch = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
    t = time.localtime(time.time())

    alarmName1 = "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits" 
    alarmName2 = "ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits"
    metric1 = cloudwatch.list_metrics(dimensions={'TableName':tableName},
                    metric_name="ConsumedReadCapacityUnits")[0]
    metric1.create_alarm(name=alarmName1, comparison='>=', threshold=0.8, period=3000,
                    evaluation_periods=1, statistic='Sum', alarm_actions=[topicArn])    
    metric2 = cloudwatch.list_metrics(dimensions={'TableName':tableName},
                    metric_name="ConsumedReadCapacityUnits")[0]
    metric2.create_alarm(name=alarmName2, comparison='>=', threshold=0.8, period=3000,
                    evaluation_periods=1, statistic='Sum', alarm_actions=[topicArn])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. CloudWatch alarms are one per metric, so for 2 metrics as you have in your code, you need 2 alarms. By the way, I think there is a typo in your code, both metric name is "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits", where I think one of them need to be "ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits".
2. Yes, Sum is the correct metric to use when monitoring the Capacity Units consumed over a time range.
3. It means notifications will only be sent if your consumed capacity units exceed 1 unit, since that is the smallest unit for capacity units. The condition on which the alarms will be sent is still your "80%" metric. If your table has 1 unit for both read and write, I don't think the alarm will ever fire (because there is no way for DynamoDB to consume 0.8 capacity units).